# Obtain Assembly attributes from unloaded executable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am attempting to retrieve the typical AssemblyInfo attributes from an executable file, but ***not*** from the currently executing assembly. I wish to 'look into' a program file (.exe) elsewhere on the drive that I have written in C#.NET and check the AssemblyProduct string.

This is fairly easy and straightforward when you're looking for this information from the currently executing assembly. However, apparently not so much when you attempt to pull it from an ***unloaded*** assembly.

When I use the following code, it returns "**Microsoft® .NET Framework**" instead of the Product name that I put in my AssemblyInfo.cs file.

**Note:** I use the `System.Reflection.AssemblyName` object to pull the version info e.g:`AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(pathToAssembly)` and this works correctly, but I'm unable to pull my assembly's attributes using that class or by any means I've tried thus far. Is there some other special class, or what am I missing or doing incorrectly here?

```
    public static string GetAppProdIDFromPath(string pathToForeignAssembly)
    {
        var atts = GetForeignAssemblyAttributes(pathToForeignAssembly);
        var id = string.Empty;
        foreach (var att in atts)
        {
            if (att.GetType() == typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute))
            {
                id = ((AssemblyProductAttribute)att).Product;
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
    
    private static object[] GetForeignAssemblyAttributes(string pathToAssembly)
    {
        if(File.Exists(pathToAssembly))
        {
            try
            {
                var assm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToAssembly);
                return assm.GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // logger etc
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw...
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what's happening here we're seeing the CLR's wrapper - and this means there's probably no reliable class/method available for peeking past these into my app domain. Soooo. I guess I'll use the old school hack and tag my assemblies with a binary fingerprint.

Comment: There's a bug in your code: instead of `return assm.GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false);` use `return assm.GetCustomAttributes(false);`

Comment: @Duncanp you are correct - that worked. I don't know why I stared at it for so long and missed that. Well, the good news is, I wrote a binary fingerprinter for all of my apps so I have that... ha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Duncanp mentioned, there is a bug in my code. Posting it for clarity and for anyone down the road who looks for the same solution:

```
public static string GetAppProdIDFromPath(string pathToForeignAssembly)
{
    var atts = GetForeignAssemblyAttributes(pathToForeignAssembly);
    var id = string.Empty;
    foreach (var att in atts)
    {
        if (att.GetType() == typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute))
        {
            id = ((AssemblyProductAttribute)att).Product;
        }
    }

    return id;
}

private static object[] GetForeignAssemblyAttributes(string pathToAssembly)
{
    if(File.Exists(pathToAssembly))
    {
        try
        {
            var assm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToAssembly);
            return assm.GetCustomAttributes(false); // fixed line
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // logger etc
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw...
    }

    return null;
}
```